# Shuffling an array except the first and the last element in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am generating a normal distribution but keeping the mean and std exactly the same by using `np.random.seed(0)`. I am trying to shuffle `r` except the first and the last elements of the array but it keeps the remaining elements at the same location in the array as shown in the current output. I also present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

mu, sigma = 50, 2.0 # mean and standard deviation
Nodes=10
r = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, Nodes)

sort_r = np.sort(r); 
r1=sort_r[::-1]

r1=r1.reshape(1,Nodes)


r2 = r.copy()

np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:]) 

r2=r2.reshape(1,Nodes)                         #actual radius values in mu(m)

maximum = r2.max()
indice1 = np.where(r2 == maximum)
r2[indice1] = r2[0][0]
r2[0][0] = maximum

r2[0][Nodes-1] = maximum  #+0.01*maximum

print("r2 with max at (0,0)=",[r2])
```

The current output for many runs is

```
r2 with max at (0,0)= [array([[54.4817864 , 51.90017684, 53.52810469, 53.73511598, 48.04544424,
        51.95747597, 50.80031442, 50.821197  , 49.7935623 , 54.4817864 ]])]
```

The expected output is (shuffling all elements randomly except the first and the last element)

```
Run 1: r2 with max at (0,0)= [array([[54.4817864 , 53.52810469, 51.90017684, ,53.73511598, 48.04544424,49.7935623 ,50.80031442, 50.821197  , 51.95747597,  54.4817864 ]])]

Run 2: r2 with max at (0,0)= [array([[54.4817864 , 51.90017684,53.52810469, 48.04544424, 53.73511598, 51.95747597,  49.7935623 ,50.80031442, 50.821197  , 54.4817864 ]])]
```

Comment: what do you consider a run? if you recreate the distribution with the same seed and call shuffle once you will always get the same permutation, that's to be expected with a fixed seed. You need to call shuffle multiple times on the already shuffled array if you want different results.

Comment: I am using fixed seed to fix the values in the normal distribution for a given mean,sigma. Given this, I want to shuffle these values so that every run throws a different ```r2```, keeping the first and last elements intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that clear from your question what do you include in a run.

If, like it seems, you're initializing distribution and seed every time, shuffling it once will always give you the same result. It must be like that because random state is fixed, just like you want your random numbers to be predictable also the shuffle operation will return always the same result.

Let me show you what I mean with some simpler code than yours:

```
# reinit distribution and seed at each run
for run in range(5):
    np.random.seed(0)
    a = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

    np.random.shuffle(a)
    print(f'{run}:{a}')
```

Which will print

```
0:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
1:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
2:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
3:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
4:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
```

What you want is to initialize your distribution once and shuffle it at each run:

```
# init distribution and just shuffle it at each run
np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(10, size=10)

for run in range(5):
    np.random.shuffle(a)
    print(f'{run}:{a}')
```

Which will print:

```
0:[2 3 9 0 3 7 4 5 3 5]
1:[9 0 3 4 2 5 7 3 3 5]
2:[2 0 3 3 3 5 7 5 4 9]
3:[5 3 5 3 0 2 7 4 9 3]
4:[3 9 3 2 5 7 3 4 0 5]
```